# Dominating pairs on a circle

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle

We have 2020 distinct numbers arranged in a circle. We say that a pair of numbers A, B is dominating if A and B are not next to each other on the circle, and on one of the two arcs between A and B, all numbers are smaller than both A and B. Find the number of dominating pairs, and show that the answer is the same, no matter how the numbers are arranged.

I've experimented with smaller cases, drawing a circle of 9, 11, 13 numbers and connecting the dominant pairs. For a while, I thought the number of pairs was just n/2 rounded up, but as the n increased, the number of pairs increased much more. I fear experimenting manually with larger numbers, because that leaves much more room for error. I long for a logical way to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck on? Did you try small cases? Did you try a specific configuration to find the number of dominating pairs (which they told you is a constant)?

Comment: Taking $n$ consecutive numbers in a circle, there are $n-3$ dominating pairs corresponding to $ n - k$ where $ 2 \leq k \leq n-2$. That suggests the numerical value for the number of pairs (unless I had some error).

Comment: This is a [contest question](https://www.math.wisc.edu/talent/sites/hilbert.math.wisc.edu.talent/files/Talent20-2q_0.pdf).  I have soft deleted the answer, and locked the question until after the contest end date.